# Amazon SES email delivery problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I have a rails application that is using Amazon SES service to send information emails to customers. In development environment this email functionality is working ok. However, when I run my application in my EC2 instance the emails are not sent anymore.

I have checked the logs, and everything looks good:

```
Rendered email_service/send_booking_request_customer_notification.html.erb (7.6ms)

Sent mail to cliente.yanpy@gmail.com (25.8ms)
Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 11:17:57 +0000
From: Yanpy <business@yanpy.com>
To: cliente.yanpy@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5457646572252_1be3fd803f643b45382f@ip-172-31-20-213.mail>
Subject: Nueva solicitud de reserva [MMSGORDH].
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5457646554c90_1be3fd803f643b4536a1";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_5457646554c90_1be3fd803f643b4536a1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_545764656fbba_1be3fd803f643b4537bb";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_545764656fbba_1be3fd803f643b4537bb
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

[text-content]

----==_mimepart_545764656fbba_1be3fd803f643b4537bb
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html>
[html-content]

----==_mimepart_545764656fbba_1be3fd803f643b4537bb--

----==_mimepart_5457646554c90_1be3fd803f643b4536a1
Content-Type: image/png;
 charset=UTF-8;
 filename=logo.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
 filename=logo.png
Content-ID: <545764654ea73_1be3fd803f643b4535ba@ip-172-31-20-213.mail>

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWAAAAB5CAYAAAAHz/urAAAACXBIWXMAAAsT
AAALEwEAmpwYAAAKTWlDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAHjanVN3...

----==_mimepart_5457646554c90_1be3fd803f643b4536a1--
```

I have checked business@yanpy.com is a verified sender email address. I even have sent a test email from SES console from business@yanpy.com to cliente.yanpy@gmail.com and the email is sent and received.

However, when I send these emails programatically, everything looks good, but the emails are not received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I have realized I was missing my smtp configuration for my test environment in Rails.

I added:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        :address => "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
        :user_name => "************", # Your SMTP user here.
        :password => "*************", # Your SMTP password here.
        :authentication => :login,
        :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
```

to my environments/test.rb config file in Rails and it worked.